# Which configuration file should I modify for Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I want to change the configuration of Nginx. Based on this article https://www.plesk.com/blog/various/nginx-configuration-guide/, I check /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and find the following info:

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN ON UPDATE.
```

Then I check /etc/nginx/conf.d, where I do not find site-specific configuration files, instead, there is a default.conf, and there is another statement said:

```
#     AUTO-GENERATED CONFIGURATION FILE: ANY MANUAL CHANGES WILL BE LOST      #
```

So this file should also not be changed. In such a case, how to change the configuration for Nginx?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` file and put here your configuration.
The comment only says that if you change this file you loose the old configuration. But as you can see this autogenerated file is super simple and you should not be afraid to loose it.
So change the `default.conf` file and reload the nginx config.